# Possible words from given alphabet up-to a maximum length

Tags: combinatorics

Say our given set is `[a, b, c]` and number of max choices `2`

Solution would be 12, i.e. `[a, b, c, aa, ab, ac, ba, bb, bc, ca, cb, cc]`

Naively, I came up with

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}l^i$$

Where $n$ is max number of choices, and $l$ is set length. Is this correct?

For our example we have possible permutations of selecting 1 from a set of 3 plus possible permutations of selecting 2 from a set of 3 which is, of course, $3^1 + 3^2 = 12$

N.B. not sure if permutations is the correct terminology her -- doesn't permutations usually refer to $^n\text{P}_r$ whereby there are no repetitions of a particular object (letter in our set).

As JMoravitz says it's more like possible strings from a given set of characters. Is there a more formal, more abstract, terminology for this?

Comment: I would first change the wording.  A permutation is a *very specific* combinatorial object with a lot of important meaning and usage, often defined as a bijective function from a finite set back to itself, or more colloquially used as a string of $n$ distinct characters taken from an $n$-letter alphabet where every letter appears *exactly once* in the string.  What you are counting are simply "strings" and not permutations.

Comment: @JMoravitz I did wonder that, just updated my question before you posted this!

Comment: As to the question of counting "How many strings of maximum length $n$ from an $l$-element alphabet exist (*with no further requirements*)" if you do not include the empty-string (*i.e. the string of length zero*) then it will indeed be $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n l^n$.  (*your choices for which variables $l$ and $n$ represent threw me off a bit*)  If you *do* include the empty string, then you need to add one more to the total to account for it.

Comment: My proof reading sucks, thank you!

Comment: So does mine apparently, I edited.  The original way you wrote it was fine and I edited my comment accordingly.  My mind wanted to go to $l$ for the maximum length and $n$ for the number of letters in the alphabet being used, but you did it in reverse.  (*Edit again: I used $n$ as the exponent instead of $i$, whoops*)

Comment: Shouldn't that be $l^i$ as top limit is implicitly $i=n$ Ahh! I don't know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As JMoravitz says it's more like possible strings from a given set of characters. Is there a more formal, more abstract, terminology for this?

There is a variety of terminology: e.g. take a look at this [report of a seminar on Combinatorics and Algorithmics of Strings](http://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2014/4552/), which starts by explaining that the subject is "*Strings (aka sequences or words)*". On a quick scan of the titles in the contents page, *word* seems to be the most popular term. I think that *word* is almost certainly going to be the most popular term among automata theorists, because they consider these objects normally as elements of *languages*. The individual elements which are chained to form them ($a$, $b$, $c$ in your example) are commonly called *symbols*, and the set of symbols is the *alphabet*, commonly denoted $\Sigma$.

The term *string* seems popular with combinatorialists, judging by a quick search experiment at the [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/), where *string* gets 3862 hits and the first page seems to use it only about sequences of symbols. *Word* gets 7259 hits, but some of those on the first page are clearly using it in other contexts. (Whether words in a Coxeter group are words in the sense of strings/sequences/words is a question of perspective: at a formal level they clearly are, but the questions which you ask about them will tend to be different). Searching for *sequence* on that site is obviously not going to cast light on this particular usage...

But e.g. one talks about [combinatorics on words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorics_on_words) rather than combinatorics on strings.

---

The number of words of length $i$ over an alphabet of size $l$ is $l^i$: if this isn't "obvious" then prove it by induction on the length. The number of words of lengths $1$ to $n$ is therefore $\sum_{i=1}^n l^i$ as you state. Note that this is a geometric progression, and can be written in closed form as $\frac{l^{n+1}-1}{l-1}-1$ or $\frac{l(l^n - 1)}{l-1}$.